# NSTimer does not call selector or repeat in time interval

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I am a newbie in objective-c and having trouble with NSTimer. While learning objective-c by developing games, I tried to move sprite using left and right button with the help of NSTimer. But, as it seems the selector is not being called. I searched stack overflow and found some solutions, but any solutions I've seen, not working. Here is my code-

```
#import "GameViewController.h"

@interface GameViewController ()
@property (strong) UIImage *playerImage;
@property (strong) UIImageView *playerView;
@property (strong) NSTimer *moveTimer;
@property CGRect playerRect;
@property int count;
@end

@implementation GameViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.count=0;
    self.playerImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ship.png"];
    self.playerView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: self.
                       playerImage];
    self.playerRect = CGRectMake(50,400, 32,32);
    self.playerView.frame = self.playerRect;
    [self.view addSubview: self.playerView];

//   this timer calls selector
//    self.moveTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.03
//                                             target:self
//                                           selector:@selector(movePlayerRight:)
//                                           userInfo:nil
//                                            repeats:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)moveLeft:(id)sender {
    [self releaseTouch];
    NSLog(@"Left Move");
//this timer does not call selector
    self.moveTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.03
                                                      target:self
                                           selector:@selector(movePlayerLeft:)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES];
//    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:self.moveTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
//    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] run];
    //[self.moveTimer fire];
}

- (IBAction)moveRight:(id)sender {
    [self releaseTouch];
    NSLog(@"Right Move");
//    if(![NSThread isMainThread])
//        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
//this timer does not call selector
    self.moveTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.03
                                                      target:self
                                           selector:@selector(movePlayerRight:)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES];

}

- (IBAction)TouchRelease:(id)sender {
    [self releaseTouch];
}

-(void) movePlayerRight:(NSTimer*)timer {
    NSLog(@"Right Move Selector");
    if(self.playerRect.origin.x <= 320){
        self.playerRect = CGRectOffset(self.playerRect, 3, 0);
        self.playerView.frame = self.playerRect;
    }
}
-(void) movePlayerLeft:(NSTimer*)timer {
    NSLog(@"Left Move Selector");
    if(self.playerRect.origin.x >= 10){
        self.playerRect = CGRectOffset(self.playerRect, -3, 0);
        self.playerView.frame = self.playerRect;
    }
}
-(void)releaseTouch{
    if(self.moveTimer != nil){
        [self.moveTimer invalidate];
        self.moveTimer = nil;
    }
}
@end
```

Let me explain what I've tried.

1. I tried with *scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval*, as shown in code. But it won't work.
2. Then I tried *timerWithTimeInterval* then with *NSRunloop*. Without *NSRunloop* [moveTimer fire] fires but NSRunLoop with repeats, it does not.
3. Then, in a solution, I found that, thread might be creating problem; So, I tried-

   ```
   if(![NSThread isMainThread])
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   ```

   But, this is not the case with the thread, as the debugger does not step in the "*dispatch_async*" line.
4. To see actually the NSTimer works, I even ran in the "*viewDidLoad*" method and it works.

What am I doing wrong?

**Solution: **
As suggested by @Danil Valeev and @aman.sood unchecked the Storyboard auto-layout, changed the property to 'nonatomic'; and now selector is being called from timer :)

Comment: Which timer isn't working? The one commented out in `viewDidLoad`? The one in `moveLeft:` or the one in `moveRight:`? Which selector isn't being called?

Comment: selector in moveLeft and moveRight are not being called. the commented method is to support my point 4 in the question.

Comment: What is supposed to call `moveLeft:` and `moveRight:`? If those methods are never called then your timers are never started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that movePlayerRight: or movePlayerLeft: are called. And that Auto Layout is not using in the view (I think it is the reason). You can disable Auto Layout in the xib/storyboard file in the first tab of Utilities.

Comment: movePlayerRight and movePlayerLeft are called ok and I disabled Auto Layout, still would not work. :(

Comment: Strange. I tried your code with disabled Auto Layout and uncommented creating the timer in viewDidLoad - works for me.

Comment: In viewDidLoad it works as I mentioned in point 4, but does not work in the  moveLeft or moveRight. :(

Comment: how do you call moveLeft: and moveRight: ?

Comment: moveLeft and moveRight are called when left and right buttons are pressed. :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace [NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] with [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] it should work

Comment: movePlayerLeft: is not even called once ? Can check by increase the time interval to 1.0. Also try adding nonatomic to @property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *moveTimer;